# Express $\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^2(1+x^2)}$ in partial fractions.

Tags: linear-algebra

I do not understand how you would know express the numerator of the $1+x^2$ as $ax +b$ instead of just $b$.

Comment: It's just a rule when you have x^2 in the denominator as one of the broken up fractions.

Comment: thanks, and what it was x^3 instead? then ax^2 +bx +c?

Comment: @grigori All cubics factor.

Comment: yes but for example if you were doing partial fractions on 1/x(x-1)^3 , then you may have one of the denomanators as (x-1)^3

Answer (score 1):

The decomposition into partial fractions should be
$$
\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^2(1+x^2)}=
\frac{A}{1-x}+\frac{B}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{Cx+D}{1+x^2}
$$
A rough justification is that, after reducing the right-hand side to the same denominator, you get at the numerator
$$
A(1-x)(1+x^2)+B(1+x^2)+(Cx+D)(1-x)^2
$$
which is a polynomial of (apparent) degree $3$, so it has four coefficients to be determined. With just
$$
\frac{C}{1+x^2}
$$
you would get just three unknowns, but still four conditions.

If you use complex numbers, you get
$$
\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^2(1+x^2)}=
\frac{A}{1-x}+\frac{B}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{C}{i+x}+\frac{D}{-i+x}
$$
and you can get back to the previous situation by noticing that
$$
\frac{C}{i+x}+\frac{D}{-i+x}=\frac{(-iC+iD)+(C+D)x}{1+x^2}
$$